# Vaex Datetime comparison

Tags: python, pandas, vaex

I have a vaex dataframe that reads from a hdf5 file. It has a date column which is read as string. I converted it into datetime. However, I am not able to do any date comparisons. I can extract day,month,year, etc from the date so the conversion is correct. But how do I perform operations like date is between x and y?

```
import vaex
import datetime

vaex_df=vaex.open('filename.hdf5')
vaex_df['pDate']=vaex_df.Date.values.astype('datetime64[ns]')
```

The datatypes are as expected

```
print(data.dtypes)
## Date            <class 'str'>
## pDate          datetime64[ns]
```

Now I need to filter out rows based on some date

```
start_date=datetime.date(2019,10,1)
vaex_df=vaex_df[(vaex_df.pDate.dt>=start_date)] 
print(vaex_df) # throws SyntaxError: invalid token
```

I get an invalid token when I try to look at the new dataframe.
I can extract the month and year separately and apply the filter. But that would give a wrong result

```
vaex_df=vaex_df[(vaex_df.pDate.dt.month>int(str(start_date)[5:7]))&(vaex_df.pDate.dt.year>=int(str(start_date)[:4]))]
```

How do I do date range comparison operations in vaex?

Comment: This could work: `start_date = datetime.datetime(2019,10,1,0,0,0).timestamp()` and then `vaex_df=vaex_df[(vaex_df.pDate.dt>=start_date)]`. Maybe you have to multiply `start_date` by 10^9.

Comment: timestamp() will make start_date float. pDate is the vaex dataframe is of DateTime format

Answer (score 6):

datetime from numpy works

```
#Instead of 
start_date=datetime.date(2019,10,1) 
#Use 
start_date=np.datetime64('2019-10-01')
```

On the vaex dataframe

```
vaex_df=vaex_df[(vaex_df.pDate>=start_date)]
```

Comment: Yes, that works, thanks. I opened an issue https://github.com/vaexio/vaex/issues/659 to support datetime object.